# MySQL MariaDB syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error, mariadb

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Nr_analizes' int NOT NULL, 'AnPacienti_id' int  NOT NULL,

This is what I get when I run SQL code in mySQL. What is happening? The sintax looks fine to me.

```
CREATE TABLE Analiza_laboratorike(
'Nr_analizes' int NOT NULL,
'AnPacienti_id' int  NOT NULL,

 'Lloji_analizes' varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    'Kategoria_pacientit' varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Nr_analizes),
    FOREIGN KEY(AnMjeku_id) REFERENCES Mjeku(Mjeku_id),
    Foreign KEY(AnPacienti_id) REFERENCES Pacienti(Pacienti_id))
```

Comment: You use the wrong TICKS ' use a backtick instead ` for the column name

Answer (score 1):

Column or tables names shouldn't be enclosed in apostrophes:

```
CREATE TABLE Analiza_laboratorike(
Nr_analizes int NOT NULL,
AnPacienti_id int  NOT NULL,

Lloji_analizes varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Kategoria_pacientit varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Nr_analizes),
FOREIGN KEY(AnMjeku_id) REFERENCES Mjeku(Mjeku_id),
Foreign KEY(AnPacienti_id) REFERENCES Pacienti(Pacienti_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the CREATE with back Ticks:

```
CREATE TABLE Analiza_laboratorike(
`Nr_analizes` INT NOT NULL,
`AnPacienti_id INT  NOT NULL,

 `Lloji_analizes` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `Kategoria_pacientit` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Nr_analizes),
    FOREIGN KEY(AnMjeku_id) REFERENCES Mjeku(Mjeku_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(AnPacienti_id) REFERENCES Pacienti(Pacienti_id))
```